# Testing the ratio of SLR coefficients

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, t-test, likelihood-ratio

Consider applying simple linear regression (SLR) to the data $\{(X_{i},Y_{i})\}_{i=1}^{n}$. Furthermore, let's assume that the errors are conditionally normal, i.e
$$Y_{i} = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1}X+e_{i}, \ e_{i}|X_{i} \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$$
I'm interested in finding the ratio $\frac{\beta_1}{\beta_0}$ of the two SLR coefficients. For a fixed constant $c>0$, suppose that we want to test the following hypothesis:
$$H_{0}: \frac{\beta_1}{\beta_0} = c, \ H_{1}: \frac{\beta_1}{\beta_0} \neq c$$
How can I construct a corresponding test of size $\alpha$, where $\alpha \in (0,1)$ is some fixed number?

I think a possible choice is the Wald test, but I'm not entirely sure...Any idea?

Comment: You could do a nonlinear Wald test. It seems simpler to test the linear reparametrization $\beta_1=c\beta_0$.